# letでの変数宣言では巻き上げが行われない？

Tags: ecmascript-6

下記で、letはブロックスコープだから、定義する前にリファレンスされるとReferenceErrorが出る、と書かれているのですが、どういう意味でしょうか？
http://postd.cc/es6-cheatsheet/

・ブロックスコープだから？
・ブロックスコープでなければ、定義前にリファレンスしてもOK？
・巻き上げは関係ないのでしょうか？
・ブロックスコープだから変数宣言の巻き上げ自体が行われない？
・それとも、ブロックスコープの先頭に巻き上げられるから？
・？？？
http://hono-auto.seesaa.net/article/433309850.html

Comment: `var`との比較でそう言っていると思います。

Comment: 原文のissue "[Clarify let and const vs var #33](https://github.com/DrkSephy/es6-cheatsheet/issues/33)"及び[文中リンク先](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/)がまさに今回の話題ですね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MDNの説明](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)より引用：

> ECMAScript 6 では let は変数をブロックの先頭へ引き上げます。しかし、その変数を宣言より前で参照することは ReferenceError を引き起こします。ブロックの始めから変数宣言が実行されるまで、変数は "temporal dead zone" の中にいるのです。

「巻き上げ(hoisting)は行われるが TDZ; Temporal Dead Zone であるため ReferenceError となる」が答えかと思います。